# how do I enable 180 degree screen rotation on Moto G (3rd gen)?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, auto-rotation, motorola-moto-g3

how do I enable 180 degree screen rotation on Moto G (3rd gen)?

Portrait is default
Landscape rotates the screen by 90 degrees

but is there a way to enable auto rotate for 180 degrees (upside down/reverse portrait) *without* root access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Rotation - Orientation Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pranavpandey.rotation) (7-day trial). It allows you to set the orientation per app or globally. "Reverse Portrait" is what you're looking for in terms of 180 degree.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Alternatively, for my Paranoid ROM (AOSP; Android 5.1), using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) I can enter on PC:

```
adb shell settings put system user_rotation 2
```

It achieves the same goal.

On further search, I found some notable mentions:

- [Rotation Anywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.RotationAnywhere)
- [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) -- full 7-day trial
- [Screen Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bong.android.androidlock)
- [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol)
- [Rotation Lock Adaptive (Free)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ui.robot.rotate) ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/2yrelo/how_do_you_enable_180_degree_rotation_reverse/))
- [Set Orientation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation) -- unsure about it

Comment: paid app. Is there a free one?

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Rotation Anywhere is only for  Android 1.5 ~ Android 4.2, not lollipop.. I will try the others -- Rotation Control looks promising